# ngOptions not working, even with base example

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select

I am very new to Angular and a bit overwhelmed.

As far as I understand, I have a component from where I can display data like `{{ this }}`, which works fine. Now, I want to have a select of that data which is in the `component.ts`. It is an array of strings:

```
private strategies: string[] = ["ASAP", "W&T"];
```

Now, in my `component.html`, I want to create a select with these strings as options.

```
<select ngModel="result" ngOptions="value for value in strategies">
</select>
{{ result }}
```

But the options list is always empty. `{{ strategies }}` yields `ASAP,W&T`, which is correct. Even if I use a base example such as:

```
<select ngModel="result" ngOptions="value for value in ['a', 'b']">
</select>
```

the options list is completely empty. What am I missing?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/bOMkG5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ngFor` on `options` to build the options in angular (v2+):
Also make sure `strategies` defined in component are public and hence accesible in template.

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="result">
    <option *ngFor="let strategy of strategies" [value]="strategy">
        {{strategy.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Also make sure you use variable name from `*ngFor`  for binding the value and display attribute for options.

`ng-options` was part of angularJS and is not used in Angular v2+.

Comment: Really? I read somewhere on Stackoverflow that this is actually bad practice. I know it works like this, but I thought ngOptions was the way to go.

Comment: Angular v2+ doesn't support `ng-options`. It was included in angularJS, it has been dropped now.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS we use `ngOptions` directive create the list of element for select but from Angular 2+ and above Angular provide the new structural directive `*ngFor` which will help to create dynamic list.

And to get selected value from the html Angular provide two way data binding directive called `ngModel`. To bind two data in Angular 2+ is little bit different like below

**Example -**

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="result">
    <option *ngFor="let strategy of strategies" [value]="strategy">
        {{strategy.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Hope this help!